# Unsupported image format

Tags: php, image, magento, gd2

[image]
I've got a problem here which keeps appearing with a message that says "Unsupported image format"

First I tried to resolve this issue and it was seem to be fixed but today when I hit the page same errors appeared. Before I resolved it by updating all the images for the articles. But I want a permanent fix for this issue. because it is clear that I will have to do the same thing over and over again which is not right way of doing things.

Does this have to do with the image format? or is there a php file or static block i need to work on?

Comment: Does your functionality use file_get_contents() any where, or any thing which requires you to use file operations?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be the module "News by CommerceLab" that causes it in the file:
`app/design/frontend/enterprise/easydry/template/clnews/list.phtml` on line 47.

Check that resize call and see if it really points to a valid image path. Probably the source will look something like `...->resizeImage($imagePath, other, stuff...);` and you could comment out the line and put this below it to see that the image path looks fine and is a valid GD2 format: `var_dump($imagePath); exit;`.

You could also turn directly to Commercelab and see if they have any bugfixes available, perhaps the module wasn't designed to work with the Enterprise version of Magento.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace points to line 51 of GD2.php as the origin of the exception. You could have a look at the code there to the particular logic that led to the exception. You might want to try using these functions to give you information about the image in question:

- [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)
- [exif_imagetype()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

Both of those functions will attempt to tell you the type of the image.

Also [gd_info()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gd-info.php) can give you useful information on what your specific server’s GD installation is capable of.